# Restore Database Stuck

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm new to mysql. I've been trying to restore a database from a backup file. I'm stuck where it's shown on the picture attached. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what does the command "show processlist;" return?

Comment: usually you must be loging in with an account that has the rights for creating tables and so on

Comment: show processlist returns: https://imgur.com/a/B6mpwLa

Comment: @nbk I do have the rights. When I try to execute above command it doesn't result anything. It's just stuck at - >. Might be a syntax error in the code. I just don't know what it is

Comment: you can try to import it with mysql workbench or phpmyadmin, check also the error log of mysql, as last resort enable general log and see what mysql is actually doing, but that log gets quickly very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are already at the mysql prompt rather than shell prompt.

At the `MariaDB [(none]>` prompt:

```
use database;
source C:\\db.sql
```

Comment: That was a stupid mistake. I'm a beginner. Still a very bad mistake. Thank you!

Comment: No harm done which is always a good start.  Wouldn't be much point in a SO site if people didn't get stuck now an then.  Suggest pure database questions to https://dba.stackexchange.com next time. Welcome to SO. Keep learning, databases are kinda fun.